# Como ver os métodos ou atributos de um objeto em Python?

Tags: python

Dado um objeto em Python, eu consigo de forma fácil listar quais métodos ou atributos ele possui, diretamente no interpretador interativo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basta utilizar a função dir(). Um exemplo da sua utilização:

```
dir(objeto)
```

Answer (score 9):

Existem algumas formas de exibir estes atributos. Considerando `obj` sendo o objeto que você deseja saber mais (sendo ele uma variável declarada ou apenas uma classe declarada).

- O mais simples e usual é o `dir`:

  ```
  dir(obj)
  ```
- Se deseja conhecer não apenas os atributos, mas seus atuais valores você pode usar também o `__dict__`:

  ```
  obj.__dict__
  ```
- Por fim, tem sempre a opção de consultar a ajuda:

  ```
  help(obj)
  ```

Answer (score 4):

É importante que você conheça o terminal do python. Isso vai ajudar muito a sua vida.

```
sudo apt-get install ipython.
```

Pode instalar na virtualenv também:

```
pip install ipython
```

Digite ipython no terminal.

Com isso você pode importar qualquer coisa do python ou classe do seu projeto.

```
from people.models import Person
#digitando 'Person.' e apertando tab, você verá todos os atributos da classe Person. Veja a imagem do link
```

Isso evitará que você faça as coisas as "cegas" e poupará muito tempo do seu trabalho.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/17V56.png